# ZipFileSystem can't open OutputStream with a slash in the path

Tags: java, scala, zip

With the following code, I get a `NoSuchFileException: data/`:
(btw: apologies for the scala syntax on a java question, but that's just the environment I'm working in)

```
val zipLocation = new File("./test.zip")
val zipUri = URI.create("jar:" + zipLocation.toPath.toUri.normalize)
val env = Map("create" -> "true").asJava
val zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipUri, env)
// so far so good
val fooInFolder = zipFS.getPath("/data/foo.txt")
val plainOldFoo = zipFS.getPath("foo.txt")

// this doesn't work
Files.newOutputStream(fooInFolder) // NoSuchFileException: data/
// this works fine
Files.newOutputStream(plainOldFoo)
```

If it makes any difference, I'm on Windows. I tried using backslashes in the paths, but it made no difference.

Why does this fail, and how can I get a ZipFileSystem to behave properly when there are slashes in my zip entry paths?

Comment: And "data/foo.txt"? Is there a directory `data` (case-sensitive) inside the zip archive?

Comment: No, but it was my (mistaken?) understanding that there's no such thing as a directory in zips. That there should simply be an entry named "data/foo.txt". If that's actually the problem, then how does one create a directory in a zip using ZipFileSystem?

Comment: (sorry if this is dumb, I'm coming from the old ZipOutputStream where you could pretty much create w/e entry you wanted)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer thanks to the hint in the comments.

Unlike with the `ZipOutputStream` class I was used to, `ZipFileSystem` requires you to create a directory before you can write files inside of it.

Adding the following before attempting to write to `fooInFolder` fixed the error.

```
val folder = zipFS.getPath("data") // or fooInFolder.getParent and a null check
Files.createDirectory(folder) // or Files.createDirectories
```